# Nova API to gather AvailabilityZone details

Tags: python, python-2.7, openstack, availability

I am able to list Nova AvailabilityZone. however i am not able to see the detail of it.

```
>>> type(nova.availability_zones.list())
<class 'novaclient.base.ListWithMeta'>
>>> 
>>> nova.availability_zones.list()
[<AvailabilityZone: internal>, <AvailabilityZone: nova>]
```

Also, object type is `<class 'novaclient.base.ListWithMeta'>`. 
I am not able to understand how to proceed and get the details. 
any help will get appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this..

```
>>> for i in nova.availability_zones.list():
...     print i
... 
<AvailabilityZone: internal>
<AvailabilityZone: nova>
<AvailabilityZone: test_zone>
>>> dir(i)
['HUMAN_ID', 'NAME_ATTR', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_add_details', '_append_request_id', '_info', '_loaded', 'api_version', 'append_request_ids', 'get', 'hosts', 'human_id', 'is_loaded', 'manager', 'request_ids', 'request_ids_setup', 'set_loaded', 'to_dict', 'x_openstack_request_ids', 'zoneName', 'zoneState']
>>> 
>>> i.to_dict()
```

It was throwing out everything in Dict. and everything was earlier than never before.  I am wondering Why I am getting the `.to_dict` only over iteration?